# Are there any good methods to run Rstudio jobs one by one?

Tags: r, rstudio

Rstudio has recently been added Jobs functionality.  It is very useful but in the open-source edition of RStudio, some function are limited.
I want to run script files using Job one by one (because of resource shortage or to use another job's output).
Are there any good methods to do it ?   Of course I can do it making up all Job scripts into one script file, but I want to avoid it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is my example.  (I'm mainly annoyed with resource shortage, but to simplify I took another situation as example)

```
## make a test script file

file.create("test_job_script.R")
cat("
    Sys.sleep(1)
    x <- x + 3
    ",
    file = "test_job_script.R",
    append = TRUE)


## one of my problem

x <- 1
for(i in 1:3) rstudioapi::jobRunScript(path = "test_job_script.R",
                                       workingDir = getwd(),
                                       importEnv = TRUE,
                                       exportEnv = "R_GlobalEnv")

x  # 4

# ### What I Want in this case

x <- 1
for(i in 1:3) x <- x + 3
x  # 10
```

Comment: Your first output is your second input.

Maybe you can put for(xxx){xxxxx} into job. in your case, put for loop into test_job_script.R.